# Ubuntu 16.04 su can claim USB device, but other users cannot

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, usb

I've just installed OceanOptics SpectraSuite in Ubuntu 16.04, which interfaces a USB digital spectrometer to the laptop.  When I execute the software as user 'instructor', it starts up without access to the hardware.  If I execute using sudo, it starts up normally and the hardware is properly initialized:

```
instructor@modern5-Latitude-E6500:~$ which spectrasuite
/usr/local/bin/spectrasuite
instructor@modern5-Latitude-E6500:~$ spectrasuite
Linux native USB library loaded.
Detected device change on USB
Could not claim device (Vid: 0x2457, Pid: 0x1022, iface: 0)
The interface could not be claimed.
^C
instructor@modern5-Latitude-E6500:~$ sudo spectrasuite
[sudo] password for instructor:
Linux native USB library loaded.
Detected device change on USB
The interface was claimed successfully.
```

How can I enable students (under a different user name) to launch this software without me needing to switch users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No satisfying solution presented itself from this end.  Fortunately, OceanOptics tech support came through with an updated configuration file (10-oceanoptics.rules) that did the trick.

Other failed approaches involved changing SELinux configuration settings (SELinux is disabled by default in 16.04), and using the 10-oceanoptics.rules file that was provided with the installation CD from February 2009.

Answer (score 1):

The device is probably connected as something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`. You can check the permissions of that device and add all the other users to the appropriate group. For example on my system I have a USB device like:

```
$ ls -al /dev/ttyUS*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Sep  1 10:00 /dev/ttyUSB0
$
```

So by adding myself to the `dialout` group (`sudo adduser myname dialout`) I can access that device. Note that other devices (such as modems and serial ports) may use the `dialout` group; if you have those devices and wanted to prevent the students from accessing them, you'd want to use a different method.

Comment: Unfortunately my /dev/tty* doesn't have any useful names that include 'USB' so I couldn't identify the device I want.  I looked at the dmesg output, which shows the spectrometer on 'usb 2-4' but doesn't specify any /dev/ label.  I added user instructor to the dialout group, tty group, and video group, but that didn't work and I still get "The interface could not be claimed."